# Omit empty elements when storing all elements of the same class in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon the click of the form button I need to put all of the text of all elements of a certain class --> 'ClassOfElementOnPage txt' on the same page of the form into a variable called 'buildingSelections' and make that the value of the hidden field before submitting with the form. Everything works! But there some elements that are empty i.e.

```
<span class="ClassOfElementOnPage txt"></span>
```

and I want to omit those from the iteration and only put the elements that have text in them in the variable, i.e.

```
<span class="ClassOfElementOnPage txt">Text to be added to variable</span>
```

Here is what I have that works, but is collecting the empty elements as well..

```
    //When form button is clicked go thru the page and stuff all the text into a variable and separated by a line break
    $('#submitButtonID').click(function(){
    var buildingSelections = "";
    $('.txt.ClassOfElementOnPage').each(function(){
  buildingSelections += $(this).text() + "<br>";
    })
    //Make the building selections hidden field value the value of the buildingSelections variable 
    $("#HiddenFieldinForm").val(buildingSelections);
    });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the loop change

```
buildingSelections += $(this).text() + "<br>";
```

to

```
var text = $(this).text();
if (text) {
    buildingSelections += text + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly :) Thanks @Adrian Brand!